# Nothing indicates that the meta site is meta....

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

While I could eventually figure out that I was in Meta and not Parent, I found myself wondering for a few seconds....I think that the design should specifically include the word meta.

I hereby suggest paying our homage to Knuth by using META with the METAFONT font: 
[image]

Comment: I like that idea, although METATEX might be clearer from a site-name perspective, especially for people who don't already know what Metafont is.

Comment: I was thinking of adding the word META as a emblem like they did in other sites, only use the METAFONT font....

Comment: Aha, I misunderstood.  Carry on, then :-)

Comment: +1, I'm convinced.  Either META or METATEX would be fine with me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have updated the Meta header, the change will be in the next deployment.

Here's what it's supposed to look like, in case you get a cached old version

[image]

I decided to put it in the same position as Parent site's fleuron, this way when you switch between the parent and meta, the {TEX} logo stays at the same location.

Comment: Nice: subtle enough not to jar, but clear enough to make the point

Comment: I like it...Thanks Jin!!

Answer (score 5):

Ah, good idea -- we usually do update the logo to include the word "meta" so we can use whatever font you like!