# Site design updates are live!

Tags: discussion, design

I'm a designer for Stack Exchange, and I wanted to give everyone a heads that minor site design updates have just launched.

Most of the changes will not be visible; these tweaks go along with recent updates that were made to Stack Overflow:

- We are moving the site's CSS to a newly refactored LESS system, so that it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally and launch new features in the future.
- We are updating the graphics to SVG for retina support.
- We've fixed a LOT of obscure bugs that arose when new features were not thoroughly tested across the entire network.

Visually it should "feel" the same as the old site with slight layout adjustments.

This update should also retro-actively fix most of the old design bugs. If you see any new bugs, or old ones not yet fixed, please post an answer here to let us know!

Comment: Here is a quick query listing [meta-tag:design] and [meta-tag:bug]-related content that have not been finished/fixed/deferred/by-design: [`[design] [bug] -[status-bydesign] -[status-completed] -[status-deferred] -[status-planned]`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design+bug+-status-bydesign+-status-completed+-status-deferred+-status-planned)

Comment: As far as TeX.SX does not have an image for its community promotions ads on other Stack Exchange sites, could you please  design an image for this purpose too? This is a relevant question: [Which image to use in community promotions ads of other Stack Exchange websites for TeX.SX?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6059/which-image-to-use-in-community-promotions-ads-of-other-stack-exchange-websites)

Comment: Cool! SVG! `:-)...`

Comment: This is not a bug, but why the change in the displayed code color scheme? Now they stand out more and make looking at code not that relaxing (like before), and also the old color scheme fit better the design of this site.

Comment: Now, it's hard to recognize between visited and unvisited questions (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions) [tested with Firefox, Chrome] . It was colored as orange and light orange before the update.

Comment: I saw the design and came here right away to see the `Eeuw!`s and `Yikes!`s :)

Comment: @Malipivo that's a bug that we will fix in the next build.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't feel the same: fonts (in the main page) and interline (in code displays) are too small.

Comment: @Manuel I didn't realize that there was custom code styling for this community. I'm pulling that same styling from the old theme and it will be live in the next production server build.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Also, the “All Questions, newest, featured, frequent, votes, active, unanswered” tabs are now blue, which stands out much more than te “brownish” that was before.

Comment: @Manuel that was an intentional change.

Comment: The response on loading of the new design sure is faster!

Comment: Thank you all for you feedback! We will get to most of these items soon.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers the change of colour for the "newest"  etc links may have been intentional but it looks terrible with the rest of the site colour scheme, for a typesetting forum these sorts of things matter.

Comment: I like red bounties!

Comment: I love it! These are words for the word count barrier.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I don't see that [this issue](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/6064/11002) would be completed.

Comment: @yo' there's no way to get complete visibility on those equations without recreating the artwork. This is a design that was previously vetted to the community. The equations are meant to be subtle artwork. And we've adjusted the positioning. If I move it more other things will get obscured.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers **i don't buy this.** When the _new black top bar_ was introduced, you -- SE -- decreased the height of the title, and this has never been corrected.

Comment: Some practical reading relative to these design changes - [Who Moved My Cheese?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Moved_My_Cheese%3F)

Comment: @Haney **I still don't buy this.** We are a typographical site, and we have a completely typographically wrong design? Sorry, that's a bit too much.

Comment: @yo' no problem, we do want to hear your concerns. However, comments aren't that practical. Please create a meta post indicating the changes you'd like. If others agree, they'll upvote it and we'll take a look at it!

Comment: @Haney The change we want is to increase the height of the title. If you want proof, you have [16 votes here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/6064/11002) and [a lot of discussion here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4007/11002).

Comment: @yo' I believe you, and I don't need proof. I'm just asking for a meta post so that we can track it in our system and improve it! :)

Comment: @Haney Ok, sorry, I didn't understand that you want a separate meta post. I'll do it tomorrow properly.

Comment: @yo' the reason for this is that the header is a separate issue that was not caused by the site conversion and we need to prioritize these tasks among others.

Comment: @yo' but we definitely want to hear your input, and fix things that are broken. :)

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Can I ask you -- do you know what was the original font (for posts and comments) and what font is it now? I'm sure the font has changed because the two hyphens used as a dash commonly on this site -- as here for instance -- now look awful, but they used to look just fine.

Comment: Changing the design a bunch of typography nerds have learned to live with -- you should have known! :D

Comment: @yo the font in the posts and comments are the same as before the site conversion. See: http://web.archive.org/web/20150330062809/http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Needed to say that archive.org doesn't store CSS style, at least not this one, for which it gives 302 and redirects to http://cdn.sstatic.net/tex/all.css?v=704dbfe2c2f6 , which is a file of unknown timestamp. Certainly what your link shows is not the original site: the numbers of comment upvotes were never this huge.

Comment: The CSS displaying in the archive is the old CSS from January of this year and not the new converted CSS.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers: Just a ping regarding [this issue](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/6073/5764) that still persists.

Answer (score 24):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can I ask why are all fonts changed? Is it a temporary thing? (*****I truly hope so!*****)

Question titles in the list are smaller, vote counts on the question page is lighter and greyer, tag names are extremely small, question text is extremly large.

---

Here is the comparison of what I see now vs what I saw before (thanks David for the archive link).

[image: click to enlarge]

Simply said: information density tends to zero, whitespace density tends to one. Why don't we simply display empty pages instead? It seems to be what you all want. */rant*

Comment: The question hyperlink is 1px smaller. It used to be 18px and now it's 17px. We will up the size in the next production build. As far as the missing logo. It's possible it's an issue of the filter in the logo's SVG not rendering. We did testing, but not on a Linux machine. There's a fallback png, but apparently FF must be trying to load the SVG if it is not falling back.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Well, I can't see the logo also on Mac OS X. I see it with Safari, probably because it is in cache, but a freshly started Firefox (which I very seldom use) doesn't display the logo. By the way, the interline in comments is too tight.

Comment: We're pushing a fix in a few minutes that should take care of it.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I see the logo now, but the colours are spoiled :(

Comment: @yo' could you be more specific? I'm looking at the old and new logo and they are the same inner color values. The only main difference is that the drop shadow is more subtle and this was an intentional design decision.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers The braces now look white, that was not the case. I unfortunately don't have the old logo, so I can't show you the difference...

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Also, the question text is maybe only very little smaller, but the box for it is larger than the Pacific Ocean. Also, the tag text and the votes/answers/views counts are very small.

Comment: @yo' compare https://web.archive.org/web/20150315031313/http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I did.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers The hyperlink is 1 px smaller and the box is almost 20% larger. ***WHY?***

Comment: The reason for the extra space is most other network sites prefer the additional padding — The white space actually allows for quicker reading of the question title. Some communities tend to prefer tighter spacing because they are used to looking at content this way, others don't. Regardless, we've removed some of the margin.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers While you removed most of the spacing, the three labels on the left of questions (votes, answers, views) are still small.

Comment: @Manuel there are some things that we want to keep consistent across the Stack Exchange network. We don't are no longer adjusting the size of those elements on a site-by-site bases.

Answer (score 23):

Could you please, while you're at it, finally fix the top title panel size? The integral on the right used to be completely visible (now the top of capital Phi is hidden), also the tengwar text on the left used to have a top padding. The arrow with `reduction` in the chemical formula is ridiculously hidden under the tabs "Users" and "Badges".

Despite [Anna Lear suggest this has been solved](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4007/11002), it has never been, and I wasn't able to convince her about it.

Comment: And I thought I was the only who is annoyed by that!

Comment: if you enter this as a new meta question, as suggested in comments, you've got a guaranteed vote here.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm working on it, but it won't be today I'm afraid.

Answer (score 20):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Code displays

The code displays are too tightly packed; here's what I see (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238485/4427)

[image]

### Profile page

In the profile page, when hovering over the list of answers (sorry, can't look at the list of questions `;-)`) they “dance”: an underlining appears, pushing down the answers below by some pixels.

This doesn't happen on Math.SE, for instance, where the changes have already been applied, AFAIK.

If I hover over the “Summary/Answers/...” bar, a “votes” moving button appears at random positions.

---

### System data

Both with Safari 7.1.4 and Firefox 37.0.1 on Mac OS X

Comment: I didn't realize that custom code formatting had been added to your theme. I will migrate the old formatting and it should be live in the next production build. Also, the links on the profile page will be fixed. I'm not sure I understand what your note about 'System data' means.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I was just telling what OS and browser I tested the bug on

Comment: Ah. I misread it.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers The fact that the code displays are the same as in [so] or other sites is not really relevant: this lack of interline space makes them look wrong if compared to the wide interline in the main text. Please, also fix the interline in comments, that's too tight.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Thanks for doing the fix! `;-)` However, the “votes” button in the profile page is still wrong

Answer (score 20):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I have <s>two</s> three issues:

1. In the homepage `https://tex.stackexchange.com/` all fonts seems to be a bit small (on 1920x1200 monitor). After the facelift, for a second I thought I have accidentally zoomed out.
2. In Ubuntu with Firefox the main logo is missing (both in the main and meta website). -- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
3. I think in the body of questions [tags](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) are shown a bit too small. (@yo' has already mentioned they are small in the homepage list as well.)

[image]

Comment: Same with win7 firefox 37.0.1.

Comment: I can confirm the vanishing of the logo on Firefox 37.0.1/Mac OS X. Indeed, the fonts are too small.

Comment: Confirmed with FF 37.0.1 on Linux; Chrome  41.0.2272.118 on Linux works,

Comment: The logo should be visible now. If you can't see it at this point, it's likely a caching issue.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I confirm them being back.

Answer (score 17):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Please, remove the cold blue colour from the title page (`active` etc. tabs). It's been mentioned in the comments here and you said that this is intentional. That doesn't change anything on the fact that it's ugly.

Comment: The blue (indeed cold) somehow doesn't work with our warm and welcoming red-brown TeX, resting on top of the page looking down to the questions with pride like an old man sitting in front of the fireplace looking at his playing grandsons.

Comment: Why is this marked “status-completed”?  Am I the only one who still sees lots of cold blue for bounties and the number of questions with active bounties?

Comment: @Thérèse This discussion was about the navigational items. The colour for bounties is fixed SE-wise and I don't suppose they're willing to be inconsistent in it from site by site.

Answer (score 14):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

We still have this issue: [Misalignment of badges/numbers on user-profile page](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5839/5764)

Here is a view of some of the flair at the bottom of a post:

[image]

And, a view of the user profile badges:

[image]

Comment: Ducks should be properly aligned. `:)`

Comment: @Werner are you still seeing this issue? If so, what browser and system are you using? I can't seem to reproduce this myself.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers: Yes. It's still visible on Google Chrome 42.0.2311.90 m; Firefox 37.0.1; IE 11,0.9600.17691 (all on Windows 7). It shows on [tex.se], but not [meta.se].

Comment: Got it. Thanks. A fix is on it's way.

Answer (score 12):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The question titles in the main *and* meta pages are not aligned:

[image]

Compare with the main page in Math.SE

[image]

Comment: I think I know *why* this is happening – the vote-counts aren't being placed an a set-width box. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/CTaX6.png for a reference.

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes, the plural forms occupy more space than the singular forms. So “1 vote – 1 answer” is smaller than “2 votes – 2 answers” (views are usually more than 1 after a short time).

Comment: I reproduced this on OSX mavericks with latest version of Firrefox. On an Ubuntu machine with both FF and Chromium however, everything seems to be aligned. Either the issue has been resolved or this is an "OSX only" type of problem...

Comment: @Pouya I think it's been solved; when I started up this morning I saw alignment.

Comment: A fix has been pushed that resolved this issue.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Thanks again for your work!

Answer (score 11):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Question/answer links on user pages**

[image]

On my user page (Meta and Main), links to questions/answers get a double underline when hovering over a certain section of them. When hovering over other "hot" areas on the same question/answer link, only a single underline appears (as I would expect).

The appearance of the second underline also causes a slight change in the height of the element, which causes the list of links to shift up and down slightly while moving the mouse.

Comment: Browser affected: Google Chrome Version 41.0.2272.101 m

Comment: This will be fixed in the next production server build. Thanks!

Comment: @KurtisBeavers now it's fixed on the main site, but meta shows _no_ underline, not a single one. Is this difference across sites intentional?

Comment: Not all the changes are live yet. They will be soon. We're getting ready to launch a new user profile across the network and that will change the layout of the profile page on both meta and the main site.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I'd much prefer that this is not marked completed until it actually is live on-site. At this point it is not.

Comment: Please extend a little trust and patience. We've been very amenable to restoring the community's site-specific customizations even though they tend to cause issues in the future when we launch Stack Exchange network-wide updates.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I don't know what about my comment makes you think I'm not trusting or patient. It's standard practice to not mark something as completed until it can be verified by the end users. *Trust, but verify* is the name of the game here.

Comment: Your original issue of the double underline posted above is live thus the status-completed tag. The issue you mention in the comments is not yet live but a production server build is in the process.

Answer (score 11):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (Werner)

*This seems to have been fixed. I gathered up as much patience as possible and waited for [multiple profile entries to have large numbers in front of them, and not wrapping occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osbAq.png). I'm sure wrapping will occur if there are more items with larger numbers, but this may not affect many users, if any.*

If you have a number of "unread" content in the user profile, the "votes" tab doesn't fit on the screen horizontally:

[image]

It dangles to the bottom-right of wherever you hover over the other tabs.

Confirmed browsers:

- Google Chrome 42.0.2311.90 m
- Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17691
- Mozilla Firefox 37.0.1

[image]

Comment: also for me it drops to another line, but it's located below "answers", on the left.  firefox 22, macbook pro / snow leopard (obviously i don't upgrade very often).

Comment: Same here, but i saw that before the update as well.

Comment: This seems to be unimportant, now, because the profile page style changed completely.

Comment: @egreg: This is the new profile page layout.

Comment: @Werner Oh, it's still buggy!

Comment: @werner, would you mind posting this issue here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list

Comment: We're tracking two different list of bugs and this particular issue is a global one that has to do with the new profile.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers: [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253754/168244).

Comment: @KurtisBeavers: When will this update be pushed? I'm still seeing the same problem.

Comment: The update has been pushed. It might be a caching issue. You might try opening in a private window or clearing your cache. Let me know if you're still having issues.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @KurtisBeavers: I don't see the problem if I have a "clean slate" (none of the blue boxes with each tab). Once I have the listed 3 blue boxes, the overflow of "votes" occurs... still (I tried with a private window in Google - incognito - since it should store any browsing history/content). Don't know whether the boxes is the main issue here and/or whether you can replicate it.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers this problem still occurs for me

Comment: @KurtisBeavers This question is still showing [status-completed] but the problem remains. Is it best just to comment here or open a new "answer"?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I still see this issue as well, and there's been no activity at the answer provided by Werner after Kurtis' request, either.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers This problem still occurs with larger numbers: http://i.stack.imgur.com/G9WHN.png

Comment: @KurtisBeavers: This is still a bug...

Comment: @KurtisBeavers: Any feedback on this bug?

Comment: I've push a fix that removed some of the margin around the tabs. This should fixe the issue. It will go live in our next production server build, and I'll post a status-completed tag when it does.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers: I'll test it when it goes live and give feedback if it persists... thanks.

Answer (score 10):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In addition to what the others have said so far, the fonts, the missing logos etc ... I see questions on their own line, i.e. some linebreak is introduced.
Same on meta, by the way.

[image: mainDistortedQs]

Ubuntu 14.04, with Mozilla Firefox 37.0.1

After the update, i see a definite improvement, or shall we say a slight change :-)

[image]

Comment: Quick questions — When you visit stackoverflow.com do you see the same problem?

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Looks normal, i can even see their logo ;-)

Comment: Btw, *not all* question have a linebreak, some look as always. But i cannot see any pattern.

Comment: I'll look into it, as I can't reproduce it myself at the moment. It may have something to do with the increased question title size. That's the problem with trying to make everything consistent yet allowing for customization at the same time.

Comment: OK, so I just pushed a change with my best guess of what might fix your issue, but I'm still unable to reproduce. Would you mind letting me know if your issue is resolved? If not, I'd be happy to hop on chat sometime to work through it together.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Thanks for taking a llok at this, i can see a change. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Ha, OK. I was at least close, but blindly bumped into something else. Will try harder!

Comment: @KurtisBeavers That issue is fixed now on my screen. But  i see the misalignment as reported in [Site design updates are live!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/6117)

Answer (score 10):

i'm not on the system i usually use, so it's hard to know whether the changes i see are system-specific, or intentional changes.

the community promotion ads seem to have disappeared.

in the header (and already mentioned) it used to be possible to actually read the tengwar, and to see clearly whether there were any superscripts or upper limits on the math formula in the upper right.  what is there now is not valid, typographically speaking.

Comment: With previous header, the braces were not red but in the same color as the background. Look at  http://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Fh4.png .

Comment: @PaulGaborit Is it really an old screenshot? Remember that archive doesn't cache pictures.

Comment: It'd be better to have one issue per answer so they can all be tracked and none are forgotten.

Comment: The brackets on Meta were white in the old site. And the community promotion ads are hosted elsewhere and should not have been impacted by this update.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers The brackets on TeX site were and should be filled with the same color as the background color. Now, they are filled with white as if they were holes in the page...

Comment: @PaulGaborit -- since it was demonstrated that my recollection of red braces was faulty, i removed that point.  so your comment about the "empty" braces should become a new entry.  (i knew they looked different though.)

Comment: @KurtisBeavers -- the community promotion ads are back for me.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Done.

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The brackets on TeX site logo were and should be filled with transparent white. Now, they are filled with opaque white as if they were holes in the page...

- Old bracket:

  [image]
- New bracket:

  [image]

Comment: I somewhat like the newer letterpressed effect.

Answer (score 9):

In the change to Retina graphics we seem to have lost the witty detail of having the meta site header echo the Metafont logo, as suggested in [Nothing indicates that the meta site is meta....](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/666/nothing-indicates-that-the-meta-site-is-meta). Could we revert to that font please?

This is what it looks like now:

[image]

This is what it used to look like:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what this asks? Are you referring to an inclusion of the Metafont logo, or that Metafont was somehow used in the user interface?

Comment: The word “META” in the site header used to be in the same font as the Metafont logo, as shown in the screenshot in Jin’s accepted answer to the question I link to. It’s not any more.

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In addition to the text being very small in the lists of tags (both favourite and related tags on the right of the main page), the interline space is huge:

[image: tags]

The interline space was too large before the update for related tags. But now, the problem is worse because the text is so much smaller, and it also affects the list of favourite tags.

Answer (score 7):

Profile tags seem a bit tight when their score contains 3 digits:

[image]

Suggestion: Perhaps a right-alignment with a fixed space as separator rather than a left-alignment would work.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image: Quack]

When I mouse over a comment of mine, the remove button has an awful vertical alignment. `:(`

Comment: Will fix. This is one reason why site-specific customization cause issues. As we adjusted the line-height on the comments, it threw off the alignment.

Answer (score 6):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) <sub>to [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253602)</sub>

[image: Quack]

The word *consecutive* is truncated. It is awful. I am very sad. Sad ducks are a sad image. Sad images make people sad as well. Please please please pretty please with sugar on top fix this. `:(`

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but would you mind posting this issue here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list

Comment: There is a team that is working through bugs on the new profile page.

Comment: @Kurtis: posted there. `:)`

Comment: when last i checked, this appeared to be fixed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: my view is still broken. `:(`

Comment: @PauloCereda -- well, since i missed a day, being on an airplane, my view hasn't got a total of 8 digits, only 5.  so it must be a function of length of that line vs. width of provided "box".  that has happened before in other situations -- maybe the "management" isn't expecting such devoted followers as you.  i suppose i should post this comment to the separate question.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

What's going on with the tags on the user profile pages?  There's a faint outline as if to shadow StackOverflow's boxy tags:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Hovering over the reputation graph underlines the graph/category labels, which shouldn't happen:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The badge-icons in the [user profile's "Badge" area](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) displays like this:

[image]

The badge icons circled in red uses the network-default dots, while the icons circled in blue uses the site-specific icons. The latter appears in most places (even when a question is closed using a gold-badge dupe-hammer) except in this location and under the [user profile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) and the accompanying "Top Tags" section:

[image]

Could we provide a consistent use of the badge-icons across all the areas they're used?

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Is there a reason why the question title is sans-serif in search results? https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=numbering+braces

I suppose it's just a missing styling for the search results.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

the size of code in comments is noticeably larger than that of text.

this may actually be a good thing, because otherwise the shapes of some letters are close to identical in the two styles.

**edit:** now that i'm back at my usual platform, i find that the size
of code in the comments is a bit smaller than that of text:

[image: screenshot of comment example]

so it's distinguishable.  (it would be really nice if different systems didn't behave so differently.)

Comment: text `code` text `more code` not code

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? I don't see it.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- the example is in my comment.  the words "code" and "more code" were input as code; "text" and "not code" we're typed in straight.  can't say whether the result looks the same on all systems; i'm seeing them as I described on a macbook with Firefox and also on an ipad mini with safari.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CcB02.png is what i see. Looks normal to me with firefox 37 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- your screenshot looks different from what i see, and i agree, both code and non-code are the same size.  unfortunately, i'm not succeeding in trying to get a "clipped" screenshot (and i'm sure nobody wants the full screen), so unless someone else can see what i've described, i'll just assume that it's limited to my system (which i know to be several releases back).  thanks.

Comment: I seem to be the only one with my problem, which, to be completely honest, is more than annoying. :-) 
[Site design updates are live!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/6068)

Comment: @barbarabeeton the fonts load in a stack based on system availability. If you don't have access to a certain font on your system then an alternate is loaded. That's probably why you are seeing one thing that others aren't. We try to use simple standard fonts, but this community is using a very diverse range of operating systems. The font in the comment and the font in the code that you're seeing are actually set to the same pixel size, but it's likely the monospace font just looks bigger.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers -- thanks.  i'll check on my "usual" platform when i get back to "civilization" on monday.  (but with the same size, it's not really easy to distinguish code from text, which can make a critical difference on this site, especially for tex newbies.  i'll check that too on monday.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very minimal issue which is not inconvenient but just a bit ugly:

[image]

In the image above, the close button of the pop-up is almost invisible (yes I know that I can click anywhere to close this window...). Interestingly, the same pop-up in SO has slightly brighter color.

Answer (score 3):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

when booting up a new session (presumably with an empty cache), the number of questions on the new page is exactly two. the option to increase this to 15/30/50 entries is offered (and the change, once made, persists), but the initial impression is very disconcerting.

Comment: This issue is not related to the CSS conversion. Would you mind posting this as a separate meta post?

Comment: @KurtisBeavers -- in meta.tex.sx or in the "main" meta?

Comment: meta.tex.sx :) We just need to track it separately.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers -- done, but it takes an *awfully* long time to appear in the questions list.

Answer (score 3):

Howering over a community in the profile page shows up the reputation and number of badges, but the badges are cut-off.

[image: cutOffBadges]

Answer (score 3):

When I look at my profile I have the track next privilege right now and since I have reach 2k rep it changes. It seems that create "tag synonyms" is larger than "edit privileges" and so the little wheel on the right that enables one to switch between track privileges and track next tag badges disappears:

[image]

### EDIT:

I have it back `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Since the update, if I want to add a picture to a post, after selecting the picture I want to upload, I have to click on the 'Add picture' button in the 'Add image' dialogue rather than being able to just hit 'Enter'.

This is driving me nuts so I'm hoping it is not a 'feature'.

Comment: This isn't something that would have been effected by the updates since we just updated the site's stylesheet. You can however post this as a separate bug report in TeX Meta.

Answer (score 0):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

The rep number under each post looks a bit too loose now, as if it were letter-spaced:

[image]

This doesn't seem desirable -- the font was designed *not to be letter-spaced*, and letter-spacing it is distracting.

Comment: I am not sure why they would be displaying differently. I double checked the font stack from the old style, and it's the exact same as the new one (font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Sans",Tahoma,sans-serif;). There isn't any letterspacing that has been added and the photo you placed in the comment doesn't match what I'm seeing in multiple browsers or images that other users have posted above. Because we're using default systems fonts. The display issue may have something to do with your system fonts.

Comment: Well, I didn't change anything in my browser, so it's strange. Is the font size changed?

Comment: @KurtisBeavers At least the size is changed. The site hurts my eyes now, whereas it did not before. Little tiny letters surrounded by lots of empty space. (I'm mostly reading this on an 11.6" laptop screen...)

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Just to make sure, this is what I see for the text of this answer (the two answers of me seems to both be font-related). Can you please confirm that it is also what you see? http://i.stack.imgur.com/TuPov.png

Comment: @yo' that's not the same thing I see. And I've gone back through the old style sheet multiple times to double check and the font stack is the same as it was before the conversion. If I had to guess your display has something to do with your systems fonts. http://i.imgur.com/ncMIXNq.png

Answer (score 0):

Where is the "log out" option ?

Apart from that, I am repeatedly faced with the same problem:

- Go on a page (not logged in),
- Click "Add a comment",
- A pop-up appears,
- Click on "Sign up using Stack Exchange",
- "Sigh… I mixed "sign in" and "log in" once again",
- Click on "Log in",
- Log in,
- "Well, this is not the page where I wanted to leave a comment, this is the front page !"

Comment: The log out option is in the Stack Exchange dropdown. The other issues you outline above wouldn't have anything to do with the update of the site's CSS. Sorry to be a pain, but would you mind creating a new TeX meta post so that we can route it appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the initial question. A new question covering the second aspect is at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6124/34551 Appart from that, great job!