# Why are these questions not properly aligned?

Tags: bug, design

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) to [egreg's post in the dupe](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6061/site-design-updates-are-live/6117#6117).

The misalignment is very apparent.  ([Specific but post-layout-uglifying image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zULc3.png))

[image: context]

Comment: Where can I find this page? Never seen it so far (embarassing). Perhaps, the bug is connected to the site redesign?

Comment: SE devs must have set `\sloppy` in the latest production code. ;-)

Comment: +1 because it's awful. However, this is already tracked in [this egreg's answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6061/site-design-updates-are-live/6117#6117).

Comment: Safari version 8.0.5 (10600.5.17); any question list.

Comment: @yo' Whoops! You're absolutely right :) I looked there, but I missed that this one wasn't [meta-tag:status-completed].